# gsub remove backslash and numbers from string

Tags: r, regex

I have a string that may have something similar to `\1` at the end that I would like to remove.

However I'm running into some problems.

```
gsub('([\\0-9])', '', 'NY \2', perl = T) ## Looking for "NY". Works fine
## NY

gsub('([\\0-9])', '', 'N Y \2', perl = T) ## Looking for "N Y". Why does this remove the space?
## NY 

gsub('([\\0-9])', '', 'N Y \2', perl = F) ## Looking for "N Y". Why does this add \00?
##  N Y \002
```

Comment: See [what string you test against](https://ideone.com/Aq3XF0). What is the real value?

Comment: can I save output of `cat` to an object?

Comment: Do you mean you have `NY \2` string? `'NY \\2'`? Do you want to remove a backslash followed with a digit? `gsub("\\\\[0-9]", "", "NY \\2")`? You seem to run into the problem that you do not know what text you have and what you need to get out of it. What is your question?

Comment: I have a string that might have a backslash followed by a number. I would like to remove the backslash and the number, while preserving everything before the backslash. Including spaces, if any.

Comment: I will close it, you just do not understand how to define a backslash in the string.

Comment: Still not quite sure about why the question was closed. The backslashes appear un-escaped in the string I'm trying to run `gsub` on--i.e. only one backslash before the digit. This ended up solving my problem:  `gsub('([^a-zA-Z| ])', '', 'N Y \2', perl = F)`

Comment: Inside `'\2'` ***string***, there is no backslash at all. If you need to remove any non-printable chars, use `gsub("[[:cntrl:]]+", "", x)`. See [`cat(gsub('[[:cntrl:]]+', '', 'N Y \2'))`](https://ideone.com/dbAYHB). Or all non-printable, `cat(gsub('[^[:print:]]+', '', 'N Y \2'))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173171/discussion-between-r-m-and-wiktor-stribizew).